# firefox not creating ticket for spnego/kerberos with client-side vue application

Tags: vue.js, firefox, kerberos, spnego

ok so i've been doing webdev for about a week and the app i'm working on is a client-side vue app talking to a backend api.

There is *very little information* on the internet about the interaction between the client-side app and the browser on the handling of kerberos ticket generation. apparently once you've got got your headers/handshake all ok the browser just [magically adds in the credentials to the request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Credentials).

I've been through all the available info and RFC on this and i think i have the correct CORS settings, and the correct browser settings for the "magic" to happen.

I've also checked that:

- kinit was successful and i have a ticket-granting-ticket
- klist shows other tickets have been granted for AD-based SSO sites
- the URL i'm hitting has an SPN created in the AD hierarchy (and has worked ok for a different project)

still no magic

what i have found is that i could enable the spnego debug logs on firefox like this:

`firefox --MOZ_LOG=negotiateauth:5 --MOZ_LOG_FILE=`

which i can see a normal spnego handshake for other stuff..

but for my particular one i get this:

`[Parent 105406: Main Thread]: D/negotiateauth nsHttpNegotiateAuth::ChallengeReceived URI blocked`

which leads me here:

https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/extensions/auth/nsHttpNegotiateAuth.cpp#176-178

with this code:

```cpp
    bool allowed =
        TestNotInPBMode(authChannel, isProxyAuth) &&
        (TestNonFqdn(uri) || mozilla::net::auth::URIMatchesPrefPattern(
                                 uri, kNegotiateAuthTrustedURIs));
```

going through these

- `TestNotInPBMode` - im not in private browsing mode
- `TestNonFqdn` - my URI requires a non-custom port 5698. but in any case i enabled `network.negotiate-auth.allow-non-fqdn` in firefox which should negate this
- `URIMatchesPrefPattern` - this is probably where the problem is but i cant really see what's wrong with what i have entered - i used a wildcard based on my domain name e.g. `.domain.com`

finally,... to try to get to the bottom of this i attempted to get a dev setup of firefox working and trace it,.. but i'm limited to rust 1.62 and so cant get the build scripts to run....